# How to create random distributions?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, model, simulation, distribution

I see nearly similar posts, though not quite and I can't seem to adapt any of them to Python. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792824/create-a-fake-dataset-that-fits-the-following-parameters-n-mean-sd-min-and) suggests an R solution using `method="SANN" in optim():` though I can't seem to duplicate it in Python. I want to create a model/plot using **(n,min,max,mean,sd,25%,50%,75%,skew, and kurtosis) as 10 known parameters WITHOUT using a distribution family**. I can do it fine with a dist family, for example:

```
x = np.linspace(39,401,100)
plt.plot(x, scipystats.???.pdf(x,p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7],p[8],p[9])
```

Then use the model for simulation using a random generator. For example:

```
ModDist = ???.rvs(p0=n,p1=min,p2=max,p3=m,p4=sd,p5=25,p6=50,p7=75,p8=s,p9=k,rs=3)
```

It does not have to be only scipy if pandas, numpy, etc.., or combined can work.
Any ideas please?

Comment: This sounds like *so* not a good idea!  If you're picking 10 values out of a hat, it's very likely that they will be mutually incompatible.  If you know ten feasible values, In my opinion you'd probably do better with distribution fitting.

Comment: I will use 10 population sample summary stats from my "describeSK()" def that I modified as discussed here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176374/how-do-i-see-and-customize-the-source-code-to-pythons-defined-functions-descri/60347793#60347793

Comment: What considerations please should I have using these 10 specific summary stats from my describeSK() in a modified pyplot.py to generate a model/plot and use with .rvs(p0=n,p1=...... for simulation?